# PHP if statement always TRUE when comparing strings

Tags: php, xhtml

I created a small xhtml form that points to a php script. No matter what I insert in the password fields they won't ever match.

What I have already done: Read in php manual about comparsion operators and make shure I was using the correct ones; Verify the if syntax to make shure there wasn't any errors; Make shure I was comparing the two correct strings and that those values were coming from the form.

I wanted to know your sugestions because I'm not getting anyware.

Thanks in advance,

berga007

Here is some samples of my code

```
<form action= "handle_reg.php" method= "post">

<p>First Name: <input type= "text" name= "first_name" size= "20" /></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type= "text" name= "last_name" size= "20" /></p>
<p>Email address: <input type= "text" name= "email" size= "20" /></p>
<p>Password: <input type= "password" name= "password" size= "20" /></p>
<p>Please confirm your password: <input type= "password" name= "confirm" size= "20" /></p>
<p>Favourite color: <input type= "text" name= "color" size= "5" /></p>

<!--Script continues but these are the lines which mattered-->
```

And now the php script

```
//Register Globals disabled
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$confirm=['confirm'];
$color=$_POST['color'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$day=$_POST['day'];
$year=$_POST['year'];

//Script continues

//Checking password
if (empty ($password) ) {

  print '<p>Please enter your password</p>';

} else {

  print '<p>You have entered your password</p>';

}

//Checking if $confirm_password matches $password
if ($password != $confirm) { //ALWAYS returning true don't know why

  print '<p>Your passwords doesn\'t match!</p>';

}
```

Comment: `$confirm=['confirm'];` should be `$confirm=$_POST['confirm'];`, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic You should post as the answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: @Gnarlywhale I don't want to answer it because it should be closed. It is just a typo.

Comment: still some bottom feeder will if you don't.

Comment: @Dagon am I the bottom feeder now? ;)

Comment: side note: size=20 is very small for names and passwords.

Comment: @Don'tPanic some else  one posted comment and deleted it really fast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$confirm=['confirm'];` should be `$confirm=$_POST['confirm'];`. That should take care of it.